# WCF service, possible to get a uniqueID for the service call?

Tags: wcf, iis

I have a WCF service. When it gets called I would like to append a unique ID of a particular call to the log.

Is there some built in way to get a unique id or GUID for a specific call to a WCF service. It is hosted in IIS, if that makes any difference.

The OperationContext.Current.SessionId only works in situations where the binding supports it, in my case I am using a basic http binding, so its a no go.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, if you enable [end-to-end tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738749.aspx) in WCF, it will add an [Activity ID SOAP header](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738751.aspx) to the message.